# Remove index.cfm by IIS URL rewriting

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-7, iis-7.5, coldfusion-10

I want to remove the index.cfm in the URL if there is there is no query_string e.g. `www.mysite.com/index.cfm` would be rewritten to `www.mysite.com` and `'www.mysite.com/Test/index.cfm` would be rewritten to `'www.mysite.com/Test/` but if there is querstring in the url then url would not be affected e.g. `'www.mysite.com/Test/index.cfm?u=5` would not be affected by rewrite rule.

How can I get it?

Comment: What about using `www.mysite.com/Test/?u=5` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfect for me

```
<rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)index.cfm" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^.*(/index.cfm/).*$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```